# Spring register ApplicationListener bean at runtime

Tags: spring

I am using

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(bean, name);
```

to register a bean at runtime. This bean could actually be considered a child bean of an existing singleton.

If the bean implements ApplicationListener, I get a warning in the log, since there is no underlying bean definition to indicate that this bean should be considered a singleton. And of course it doesn't receive application events, like the warning says.

```
Inner bean 'name' implements ApplicationListener interface but is not reachable for event multicasting by its containing ApplicationContext because it does not have singleton scope. Only top-level listener beans are allowed to be of non-singleton scope.
```

How can I register the bean as singleton at runtime, so I avoid the bean post processor warning, as well as have application events work?

(See AbstractApplicationContext:1413)

Comment: Why are you manually initializing beans? Why aren't you simply configuring them as the other beans (maybe utilizing Java based configuration for this?).

Comment: By the time you call `initializeBean`, the context is already initialized and `ApplicationListener` beans are already registered.

Comment: have you tried this answer: [How to register a Spring ApplicationListener implementation through code?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38250746/48229) It suggests `context.addApplicationListener(new CustomEventHandler())`