# How to register a Spring ApplicationListener implementation through code?

Tags: java, spring

I've an implementation of Spring `ApplicationListener`. It works fine and receives events when it's declared as a bean in context xml file or if I use `@Component` annotation.

However, it doesn't receive events if I manually register it through code using the `ConfigurableListableBeanFactory`'s `registerSingleton()` method.

I've added some sample code below that describes working and not working cases.

CustomEvent.java

```
package com.test.event;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

public class CustomEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    public CustomEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "My Custom Event";
    }
}
```

CustomEventPublisher.java

```
package com.test.event;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEventPublisherAware;

public class CustomEventPublisher implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void publish() {
        CustomEvent ce = new CustomEvent(this);
        publisher.publishEvent(ce);
    }
}
```

CustomEventHandler.java

```
package com.test.event;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class CustomEventHandler 
   implements ApplicationListener<CustomEvent>{

   public void onApplicationEvent(CustomEvent event) {
      System.out.println(event.toString());
   }

}
```

applicationContextWithListenerBean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="customEventHandler" 
      class="com.test.event.CustomEventHandler"/>

   <bean id="customEventPublisher" 
      class="com.test.event.CustomEventPublisher"/>

</beans>
```

applicationContextWithoutListenerBean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="customEventPublisher" 
      class="com.test.event.CustomEventPublisher"/>

</beans>
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.test.event;

import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        /* The below code works fine when listener bean customEventHandler is defined in xml */

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContextWithListenerBean.xml");
        CustomEventPublisher cvp = (CustomEventPublisher) context
                .getBean("customEventPublisher");
        cvp.publish();
        context.close();

        /* The below code doesn't work when listener bean is registered through code. Is it possible to make this work? */

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "applicationContextWithoutListenerBean.xml");
        context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("customEventHandler",
                new CustomEventHandler());
        CustomEventPublisher cvp = (CustomEventPublisher) context
                .getBean("customEventPublisher");

        cvp.publish();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to register an `ApplicationListener` through code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Registering the bean as a singleton will not enable it to be called back on ApplicationEvents.

```
context.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton("customEventHandler",
            new CustomEventHandler());
```

should be changed to

```
context.addApplicationListener(new CustomEventHandler());
```

This will add the ApplicationListener implementation to the [ApplicationEventMulticaster](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationEventMulticaster.html) which publishes events to [ApplicationListeners](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html)

Comment: I've the reference to ApplicationContext. Given this bean and application context, is there a way to make it receive ApplicationEvent through code?

Comment: Post the code to show your working example and non working example.

Comment: I have posted some sample code describing the working and not working cases. Please see if you can help.